# Lumen Passport returns Unauthorized error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-passport

[Lumen auth:api always comes back Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178613/lumen-authapi-always-comes-back-unauthorized)

https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport package used.

And his step follow. token also generate.

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($app){
        $app->get('all_languages',  ['uses' => 'ListController@getAllLanguages']);
});
```

but always Unauthorized error get.

token also pass in header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the token in the `Headers`, click on the `Authorization` tab which is located left side next to the `Headers` tab, and under that choose the `Type` (Token Type) as `Bearer` and then paste your token over there. Now Send the request.

Below is a screenshot of how to do it
[image]

Comment: Did you remove the Authorization key in `Headers` before you putting the token in `Authorization` tab?

Comment: .htaccess also check, add logger Authenticate.php middleware token also print in log file

Comment: yes remove in header Authorization key, Authorization tab outh 2.0 add my auth url and url detail token generate that token used.

Comment: any other suggestion its help me :(

Comment: @JimitH.I saw the screenshot. Do not choose the token `Type` as `OAuth 2.0`, instead choose `Bearer` as the `Token` type as I said you in my answer. So if you choose `Bearer`, all you have to do is entering only the `Token` nothing else (like you don't need to enter the token expiration date).

Comment: @JimitH. I have included a screenshot of it in my answer which will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

**lumen-passport** in that multiple grant-type available see below document ref. link

https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/

my problem is generate **client_credentials** that token used in auth token so that always return **Unauthorized** error.

so i used **password** grant-type and generate token and that token used in api and it will work.

http://localhost/api/public/oauth/token

```
{
 "grant_type": "password",
 "scope": "*",
 "client_id": "client_id",
 "client_secret": "client_secret",
 "username":"username,
 "password":"password"
}
```

and output is

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31622400,
    "access_token": "token_here",
    "refresh_token": "refresh_token"
}
```

and access_token used in api so it will worked.

**client_credentials** grant-type not available in lumen-passport

but using laravel passport you can implement that.

**App\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials.php** create file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory;

class CheckClientCredentials
{
    /**
     * The Resource Server instance.
     *
     * @var \League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer
     */
    private $server;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer  $server
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceServer $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  mixed  ...$scopes
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try {
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            //throw new AuthenticationException;
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);            
        }

        $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the scopes on the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $psr
     * @param  array  $scopes
     * @return void
     * @throws \Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException
     */
    protected function validateScopes($psr, $scopes)
    {
        if (in_array('*', $tokenScopes = $psr->getAttribute('oauth_scopes'))) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
            if (! in_array($scope, $tokenScopes)) {
                throw new MissingScopeException($scope);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**bootstrap\app.php** change file

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
        'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,      
        'client_credentials' => App\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
]);
```

**web.php**

```
 $app->group(['middleware' => 'client_credentials'], function () use ($app) {
        $app->get('/user', ['uses' => 'UserController@getAllUser']);            
    });
```

and for token

http://localhost/api/public/oauth/token

```
{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "client_id",
  "client_secret": "client_secret"
}
```

output

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 5400,
    "access_token": "access_token_here"
}
```

that token used header and it will work for me.